# Python API script that is linked to an excel sheet and sends SMS texts as appointments are updated on the sheet

Tags: python, excel, sms

So I am trying to build a python script that would send out a text message as appointments were updated on the excel that are sent 7 days before the appointment is. I already have an SMS texting client to work with I am just curious as to what info could be shared or websites that could help with beginning the code for what I am thinking of. To go into detail on this there is an excel that is updated with new appointments daily so I am hoping to have the script always checking the script for appointments that are in exactly 7 days, sending out an SMS text to those patients, and replying back to them if they respond Y or N with the appropriate response to each of them. I have novice experience with Python and might not be explaining this in a realistic way and if so then let me know. I am completely new to the idea of this and already have some code started for separating answers between the yes and the no's to give a better understanding of what I am trying to create.

```
for_yes = ['y','yes','Yes','Y']
for_no = ['n','No','no','N']

if body in for_no:
    response = notifications_client.send_sms_notification(
        phone_number = 'From Excel with received texts', 
        template_id = '', 
    personalisation = {
        'first_name': '',
        'appointment_date': '',
        'GP Name': '', 
    }
    )



if body in for_yes:
    response = notifications_client.send_sms_notification(
        phone_number='From Excel', 
        template_id='',
    )
```